# No Android or IOS specific files on React Native Project Folder

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I followed React Native Official Doc Step By Step from

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

and initialized a project and got the following files (except splash.js and style.js)

[image: Screenshot]

For learning React Native I was following a youtube video and in there the project folder contained some android and ios specific files.

But I ran the project by creating a simple splash screen and it's running on both android or ios file.

As a beginner I'm so confused. So How can i get those files.

For Example,

- index.ios.js
- Index.android.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just double check that you follow this instructions https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html and not something else.

Now what i am doing is

1) npm install -g react-native-cli

2) react-native init AwesomeProject

3) cd AwesomeProject

4) react-native run-ios

Answer (score 3):

you are using expo if you want native code try Building Projects with Native Code tab on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#getting-started